# Linq return bool where a = val1 & b = val2 from model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 for loops and need to check if the model contains value based on current ones.

```
<% for (int currentDay = 1; currentDay <= 7; currentDay++)
       {  %>
        <%=Html.CheckBox("TimeRange" + currentDay.ToString())%>
    <%} %>
```

Somehow I need to make the checkbox checked if the model contains data based on 2 parameters (i just put the first loop there)

Kida like:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("TimeRange..", (bool)Model.Timetable.Contains(x => x.Time == timeval && x => x.DayOfWeek = i))%>
```

How is that done?

/M

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I any you want [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) rather than [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx), and your syntax is a bit off. Try this:

```
Model.Timetable.Any(x => x.Time == timeval && x.DayOfWeek == i)
```

Note that it's just one lambda expression, so there's only one `x =>` bit, and also note the `==` instead of `=` in the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, not familiar with your data though..

```
Model.Timetable.Any(x => x.Time == timeval && x.DayOfWeek == i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.Timetable.ToList().Any ...
```

Else it will try to execute that on SQL and will likely fail.